# try_files always returns 404 with variable

Tags: nginx

The `try_files` directive seem to always fail for me:

```
...

root /images;

location /media {
    set $do_resize $uri;
    # if ?resize=blah query present, rewrites do_resize to small/$uri
    if ($arg_resize != '') {
        set $do_resize 'small/${do_resize}';
    }
    try_files $do_resize $do_resize/ @fallback;
}

# placeholder for image resize server
location @fallback {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 "not found :/";
}
```

My folder structure:

```
| images
    | test.jpeg
    | small
        test.jpeg
```

When requesting to `http://foo/media/test.jpeg`, it returns the image correctly. but when requesting `http://foo/media/test.jpeg?resize=blah`, it returns 404 not found. It should return the `test.jpeg` image inside the `small` folder.

Is it possible to `try_files` with a custom variable at all? I've never seen something else besides `$uri` being used for the `try_files` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement does not work inside the `location` block for some reason, but the use of `if` inside a `location` block is known to cause problems. See [this application note](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Also, all `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`. So, the `$do_resize` inside the `if` block should be `/small$uri`.

For example:

```
set $do_resize $uri;
if ($arg_resize != '') {
    set $do_resize /small$uri;
}

location /media {
    try_files $do_resize $do_resize/ @fallback;
}
```

Comment: bugger! I've been scratching my head to why sometimes the request behaves oddly while other times it doesn't. that's exactly what's explained in the link you mentioned :( so it's completely legit to use a variable for the `try_files` directive? I will try this later when I'm back at the office. thanks

Comment: I have confirmed that it is indeed possible to use `try_files` with custom variables. Thanks